.NET RemoteCertificateNameMismatch occurs between two local apps on Mac, but works fine on Windows
I have a pair of .NET Core demo apps for my open-source project that can communicate via SSL.
When I run them both on Windows, everything is fine.  But when I run them both on my Mac, I get a RemoteCertificateNameMismatch error.
The exception is:
<event> Connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 5001
<event> Remote certificate was not recognized as a valid certificate: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
<event> Unable to perform authentication against server: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
<event> Connection failed: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate was rejected by the provided RemoteCertificateValidationCallback.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at [a few more lines of my app code...]
   ...

I'm running the server/client pair identically on each platform-- same cert, same CA cert, same cert password, the client points at 127.0.0.1, etc.
What am I missing?  What is Mac doing differently here that I'm not accounting for?
If it helps, the apps "Executor" (server) and "TradeClient" (client) are here: https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/tree/master/Examples
(I know SO prefers in-lined context over links, but I don't know what's relevant.  I will revise this question with relevant context once I learn what that context is could be.)

Have you debugged the VerifyRemoteCertificate function in your source? https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/8d0a5edacf4b8dd4e1ce299e166f53a0d7cd6a66/QuickFIXn/Transport/SslStreamFactory.cs#L156 it appears to be logging stuff, what do the logs say? I must say, that function looks to be terrible at validating the certificate: you should have added the CA cert to the Trusted Root store (both Windows and Mac) and used a better DNS name than localhost which cannot be verified. If they are both running on the same machine then it might make sense to just pin the exact certificate used.

How is the server certificate generated, is it the same in both cases?  Are both cases using the same connection-string/URL (e.g. if Windows uses https://localhost/ and macOS uses https://127.0.0.1/ then the cert requirements are different)

@Charlieface The output above shows all the messages that were logged.  If you suggest other logging that could help, I can add it.  Regarding the rest: As this is just a small demo app, (1) I'd prefer not to require adding anything to the OS's store, and (2) localhost is perfectly acceptable for this purpose. I want anyone to be able to just check out this repo and run it as-is. I'm sure the verification logic could be improved, but not by me yet, I still kind of suck at this.

@bartonjs All the certs were generated a few years ago on a Windows machine, and continue to work on any Windows machine without needing any local changes (which is the intent). Regardless of Mac or Windows, both platforms are using the exact same config files and thus the same destination URL, which is "127.0.0.1" (as can be seen in tradeclient_ssl.cfg => SocketConnectHost).

Then why not just pin the certificates if they are fixed in that way? Essentially it comes down to the line // Just use any certificate (if there is one) where you just blindly pick a random cert, which may or may not work. So change VerifyRemoteCertificate to just check the cert itself is valid (excluding the chain building) and match on the exact serial number. And change SelectLocalCertificate to only return that certificate. What other logging: i don't know, but debugging VerifyRemoteCertificate and telling us what exactly is happening would be a good start.

@Charlieface I already tried debugging the VerifyRemoteCertificate logic reasonably far into the C# SSL library stack, to where it starts accessing byte-encoded cert data structures.  Predictably, thus error traces to a point where the app's specified cert name is checked against a string in a cert, and it doesn't match.  That's not really a surprise -- it's exactly what RemoteCertificateNameMismatch implies.

Curiosity having gotten the better of me, AFAICT, you are using a cert with CN=QuickFixn-Server and no SubjectAlternativeName extension.  It's correct that it's failing on mac (no SAN, so match against CN, and it doesn't match)... the mystery is why it isn't failing on Windows.
Rather than solve the mystery of what sort of compatibility gap you fell into on Windows, recreate your cert with a proper SubjectAlternativeName extension.  (And since you're connecting to 127.0.0.1, that needs to be encoded as an iPAddress, not a dNSName)

Is the SAN only needed by the Server Cert?  I'm guessing the CA cert doesn't need it.  Is that correct?

I tried recreating the certs, but haven't gotten it right.  Through a lot of openssl command trial-and-error, I've somehow circled back to getting RemoteCertificateNameMismatch again.  Would you mind looking at my cert-creation scripts and seeing if I've made any obvious mistakes?
